# Python Grid layout problems

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making a clock app and I had problems with the `.grid` method, The keys inside the frame didn't respond to the given directions, I also tried using the `.grid` with the frame but the situation was the same, then I removed the frame and placed the keys to the gui but nothing has changed.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time 


gui = Tk(className="Clock")
gui.geometry("800x800")

frame1 = Frame(gui,height=50,width=200)
frame1.pack(fill="x")

fuso_orario = Button(frame1, text="Fuso orario", height=2)
fuso_orario.grid(row=0,column=0)

sveglia = Button(frame1, text="Sveglia", height=2)
sveglia.grid(row=0,column=1)



gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what is your problem? That your buttons don't execute the correct commands, or that they are not drawn properly? Its not clear from your description

Comment: buttons don't execute the correct commands

Comment: There is no command associated with the buttons.

Comment: This code works fine for me. You put the buttons in columns 0 and 1 and they appear in columns zero and one. Where did you expect them to appear?

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're facing is due to mixing the `pack` and `grid` geometry managers in the same master widget. You should not use both `pack` and `grid` within the same master container.

To fix this issue, you can stick with only one geometry manager. Here's how you can use the `grid` manager for your application:

1. Use the `grid` method to place the `frame1` into the main window `gui`.
2. Use the `grid` method to place the buttons inside `

   ```
    from tkinter import *
    import time 

    gui = Tk(className="Clock")
    gui.geometry("800x800")

    frame1 = Frame(gui, height=50, width=200)
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")  # Using grid to place the frame

    fuso_orario = Button(frame1, text="Fuso orario", height=2)
    fuso_orario.grid(row=0, column=0)

    sveglia = Button(frame1, text="Sveglia", height=2)
    sveglia.grid(row=0, column=1)

    gui.mainloop()
   ```

Now, the `frame1` frame and its child buttons are all managed by the `grid` geometry manager, which should fix the layout issue.

Comment: There is no mixing of geometry managers here; `gui`'s child is managed by `.pack()`, and `frame1`'s children are managed by `.grid()`.  There is absolutely no problem with doing it that way.

Comment: I have still that problem

Comment: _"The problem you're facing is due to mixing the pack and grid geometry managers in the same master widget."_ - no they aren't. `frame1` is in the only widget in root and it uses `pack`, and `fuso_orario` and `sveglia` are in `frame1` and they use `grid`. This is valid, and arguably a best practice.